# ionic 3 - html table/ion-list scroll very slow

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, wkwebview

We’ve an html table in a page created using a ngFor. The scroll of this table it’s very slow in ipad mini 2/4 (no problems with android and iphone 6/7/7 plus) also with only 50 rows. Also the selection of the rows is very slow (we’ve a checkbox for each row, with or without click event).

- We’re using the ionic wkwebview.
- We’ve removed all unecessary code in order to exclude some our slow business logic and we’re trying with just one column.
- We are using the workaround specificied [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12733)
- We’ve tested also with ion-grid (instead html table), but the situation remains the one described above and in this view we have the constraint of vertical and horizontal scroll.
- We’ve also used the ion-list with virtual/infinite scroll, but no improvements also in this way.

**Page HTML**

```
<div style="overflow:scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
   <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" *ngIf="isDataLoaded">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{{ 'general.sel' | translate }}</th>
        <th style="text-align:left" *ngFor="let column of visibleColumns">{{column.description}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody [style.height]="tableHeight">

      <tr *ngFor="let row of gridData.data;  let rowIndex = index">

        <td tappable (click)="selectRow(row, rowIndex)">
          <input  type="checkbox" [checked]="row.selected">
        </td>

        <td style="text-align:left" *ngFor="let column of visibleColumns">
          <p>{{row[column.code].valueLabel}}</p>
        </td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

**ionic info output**

```
cli packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.1
    ios-sim    : 5.0.4
    Node       : v6.11.3
    npm        : 3.10.10
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

What could be the problem? Is there a workaround to solve it?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: iPad is very slow for our ionic App too but other apps were also slow for us in that device. Please check whether all other apps are running smoothly in your ipad

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We've solved using the script indicated in this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12733). See my answer below.

Comment: Great to know. I will also try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Removing this (as indicated in this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12733))

```
:focus,
:active {
outline: none;
}
```

from main.css solve the problem. There was a problem in our script and the code was not removed during the build, Now it works well!